# How to Install a Github Ruby On Rails Project on a Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, digital-ocean

I have a digital ocean droplet that automatically sets up Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nginx and Unicorn.  I'm trying to get a Ruby on Rails application running from github (https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr) but just copying the files over doesn't seem to be working. I'm not a rails expert, so any help you can give would be great. It looks like the github project is a complete, working app, I just need to figure out how to get it working on my digital ocean droplet. I can't find any guides on this either!

EDIT: I Figured this out with some help from digital ocean!  Install the ruby on rails droplet, and then ssh into the droplet and do the following:

```
rm -rf /home/rails/*
cd  /home/rails/
git clone https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr.git .
nano Gemfile # Add "gem 'mysql2'"
nano config/database.yml # Change 'postgres' to 'mysql2' and add user/pass for the database
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx  # Uninstall gems that might conflict
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load db:seed
nano config/environments/production.rb # Set `config.assets.compile = true`
chown -R rails:www-data *
service unicorn restart
exec bundle rails s -d
```

Your app should now be up and running at yourip:3000 woo hoo!

Comment: see https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tags/ruby-on-rails

Comment: this one seems more specific https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Neither of those really get into how to install from github...

Comment: ah, now I understand your question, there is one big thing you need to change from that tutorial, when they say, `rails new testapp --skip-bundle` you need to actually copy the files from your local repo to a folder in digital ocean, you can do that through git or ssh. There are many ways to do that, the important thing is that you copy the folder.

Comment: I figured it out with some help form digital ocean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured this out with some help from digital ocean! Install the ruby on rails droplet, and then ssh into the droplet and do the following:

```sh
rm -rf /home/rails/*
cd  /home/rails/
git clone https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr.git .
nano Gemfile # Add "gem 'mysql2'"
nano config/database.yml # Change 'postgres' to 'mysql2' and add user/pass for the database
gem list | cut -d" " -f1 | xargs gem uninstall -aIx  # Uninstall gems that might conflict
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create db:schema:load db:seed
nano config/environments/production.rb # Set `config.assets.compile = true`
chown -R rails:www-data *
service unicorn restart
exec bundle rails s -d
```

Your app should now be up and running at yourip:3000 woo hoo!